# Is there a word or expression when you are thinking too much?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, expressions

When you are thinking too much and creating situations that will never happen when solving a problem, is there an expression or word for this? What is a better way to express this idea without using "thinking too much" or is this fine?

Comment: please give a context in which you would use the word or expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The word is "overthinking".

> Overthink—to think too much about (something); to put too
> much time into thinking about or analyzing (something) in a way
> that is more harmful than helpful
>
> — [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overthink#:%7E:text=%3A%20to%20think%20too%20much%20about,I%20went%20to%20New%20York.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the world **overthink**.

> **Overthink (verb):** to think about something too much, in a way that is not useful:
> Eg: I overthink everything and worry too much.

[[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/overthink).

You can also use the sentence "think too much" to express the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

***exaggerating things*** would be one option. Also, many of the OVER- verbs would also do the job. I personally like **overdramatize** because it reminds me of the funny expression ["to be a drama queen"](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk02jR1OushP-QQF5pByckeoPUr-qcg%3A1608219204953&ei=RHrbX5jZOd2g1fAPyfen2As&q=to%20be%20a%20drama%20queen%20meaning&oq=to%20be%20a%20drama%20queen%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQRzoECAAQQzoGCAAQBxAeOgcIABAUEIcCOgwIABCxAxBDEEYQ-QE6CAgAEAcQChAeOggIABAIEAcQHjoECCEQClCmuRBY7uIQYMnqEGgBcAN4AIABrwGIAa4WkgEEMC4yMJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiYi7qzq9XtAhVdUBUIHcn7CbsQ4dUDCA0&uact=5).
Other idiomatic expressions you might like are

> [worry over nothing](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk03aqtiD7Eq8740_uhxNzCY3qyjTJQ%3A1608219585520&ei=wXvbX7-cH7KC1fAPlry9iAc&q=worry%20over%20nothing%20meaning&oq=worry%20over%20nothing%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQHjoGCAAQBxAeUKLZAljl6gJgz-0CaAFwAXgAgAGqA4gBzQqSAQkwLjMuMi4wLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj_gPborNXtAhUyQRUIHRZeD3EQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)
>
> make a big deal
>
> press the panic button
>
> blow things out of proportion